# Using new Delphi 10.4 community Tools>Options>Language>Delphi Options>Library enter library paths Add button does not work

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

Delphi 10.4 I want to add system-wide paths so existing software from 10.1 compiles.  In Tools>Options>Language>Delphi Options>Library the ADD button is non-functional.  How can I add system-wide paths as could be done in 10.1?

Comment: I just tried it in 10.4, and the button did work. But even without the button, you can simply edit the semicolon-separated list in the edit box.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not as clear as it should be.  Please describe "non-functional"?  I am taking a guess here... the Add button looks disabled when you first bring up the Directories screen as shown here in this screenshot:

[image]

You can click the Open folder icon to select a path (or enter a new path) and then the Add button will become enabled.

Comment: Same behaviour in Delphi 11.1